# Select row with direct and indirect relation of other row and with specific ID

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

**UPDATE2** : For better understanding, here is a pseudo code (i am sure that is not the best way to code this) and i need SQL request not js/java/... :

```
map_id = 2
desiredResult = []
direct = []
maybeContainDirectBird = []
possibleIndirect = []
indirect = []

direct = selectAllBirdFromMapId(map_id)

foreach (element of direct){
    foreach (map of element.maps){
        possibleIndirect = selectAllBirdFromMapId(map)
        foreach (possibleBird of possibleIndirect){
            foreach (mapLvl2 of possibleBird.maps){
                maybeContainDirectBird = selectAllBirdFromMapId(mapLvl2)
                if (maybeContainDirectBird contain >1 element of direct){
                         indirect.push(possibleBird)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
desiredResult.push(direct)
desiredResult.push(indirect)

selectAllBirdFromMapId(id){
    return array of bird object with mysql request "Select * FROM part 
where map_id=&id"
    example : [{bird_id:2, maps:[1,2,3]}]
}`
```

**UPDATE1 :** As i see it can be hard to understand what i need, i removed column `postion` and updated image

I need direct relation (red circle) data using map_id and also indirect in a first level relation (Grey circle) between 2 red circle but not no relation or more deeply relation (Blue circle)

---

i don't know how to name my problem...
I need help to request my mysql database.

I have a table `part` with :

```
|id | map_id | bird_id | 
  1     1         1         
  2     1         2         
  3     1         3         
  4     1         4         
  5     2         2         
  6     2         5         
  7     2         8         
  8     2         6         
  9     3         2          
  10    3         10        
  11    3         5         
  12    4         5         
  13    4         9          
  14    5         5         
  15    5         4         
  16    6         6          
  17    6         3          
  18    7         6          
  19    7         7
```

I need to select every part that is directly or 1 step deeply in relation with one particular part. For example if i set `where map_id = 1` it should return to me :

```
|id | map_id | bird_id | 
  1     1         1         
  2     1         2        
  3     1         3         
  4     1         4         
  6     2         5         
  8     2         6        
  14    5         5          
  15    5         4         
  16    6         6          
  17    6         3
```

Here is graphical version of my database:

[image]

If I want stats for every bird in the green relation with 1 step more deeply, I need to get few yellow + brown + dark brown relation.
(red circle = direct relation bird, gray circle = 1 step deep relation bird, blue circle is bird that I don't need).

In this example, I know `id` of bird but my database is bigger, I need to make request that work in any case of bird `count`/`id`/`map_id`

Thank you for your help

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? (Although I confess I fail to see why any rows are excluded from your result)

Comment: I'm using MySQL 8. If you look on image link, you can see 2 grey circle, i need data from them to evaluate the red circle (in my case, more data = better accuracy). It just a select with one step deeper but i don't know how to write request like this... the final result will be graph like this : https://github.com/sgratzl/chartjs-chart-graph  with only interresting "bird"

Comment: Nope, still as clear as mud to me, but no doubt someone will figure out what you are going on about

Comment: @Julien . . . The question just makes no sense to the outside observer.  The image only makes things more confusing.  In particular, what "one step" means in this context is just unknown.  And a table called "part" with a `bird_id` does clarify what might really be happening.

Comment: It seems that your request for `map_id = 1` should contain this record from `parts` table: `7     2         8         4`? Why circle with number 8 is blue which you don't need? This not follows from table data.

Comment: Thank you for post edit and sorry for my poor english... No, i don't need circle with number 8 because it has no direct relation with map_id 2 (green line) and also it is not 
 "one level deeper" relation with it. (for this example, circle with number 8 have two level deep and i only need 1 level deep).

Comment: I failed to understand how postion is being generated what does it mean in the table ? How does it relate to other two columns ?

Comment: Sooo it's basically a two-way linked list?

Comment: If you only need the "one step" up and "one step" down then you could do it with subqueries probably. `SELECT id FROM part WHERE map_id in(SELECT id FROM part WHERE map_id = 2) OR bird_id in(SELECT id FROM part WHERE bird_id = 2) OR id = 2` or something like that

Comment: @user3647971 , it is not exactly what i need. Also no need to select all "2" value.

Comment: @julien I think I get it now. `SELECT * FROM part WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM part WHERE (map_id = 1 OR map_id IN(SELECT map_id FROM part WHERE bird_id IN(SELECT bird_id FROM part WHERE map_id = 1))))` not sure tho.

Comment: @user3647971 Thank you, it still not what i exactly want because i see in result few row that i dont need like bird_id 8 but for now it is the best answer i have . You can take a look to this db-fiddle: [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/amh7inLRNJSez8iGNoX22z/1) the result is not exactly the same as i want

Comment: @julien Umm why are the bird_id 10 and 8 not wanted in the results? 10 is mapped directly with 2.

Comment: @user3647971 Because it should have 2 point of relation between one interresting point (2 red circle) . If you look at circle 5, it have relation bettwen 2 and 4, circle 6 have relation between 2 and 3 but 8 and 10 have only 1 relation with 2 (the relation with other circle like circle 5 is a two level deeper and i only want one level deeper)

Comment: @user3647971 i think your request `SELECT * FROM part WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM part WHERE (map_id = 1 OR map_id IN(SELECT map_id FROM part WHERE bird_id IN(SELECT bird_id FROM part WHERE map_id = 1))))` is good, but it look like it miss a AND operator to be sure it has relation bettwenn 2 red circle

Comment: @julien yeah, maybe should use another subquery with HAVING clause with it. Not sure how exactly tho.

Comment: SELECT * FROM part WHERE map_id = 1 OR id IN(SELECT id FROM part WHERE bird_id IN(SELECT bird_id FROM part WHERE map_id = 1) HAVING count(bird_id) > 1) Is best I can do

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get the good result but thank you for your help !